# How to access parent class variable in child class inside a child method?

Tags: java

I have a class

```
public class A {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string getName(){return name;}

    public String toString() {
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       builder.append(name).append(", ");
       return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

I have a child class B that extends A and I have to access name from A in toString method in B. I have written the following code but not sure if this a good practice?

```
public class B extends A {
    private String gender;

    public void setGender(String gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public string getGender(){return gender;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       c = new A();
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       builder.append(c.getName()).append(", ");
       builder.append(gender).append(", ");
       return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If I cannot access private String name in class B, do I have to `@Override setName()` by using `super.setName(name)`? In that case how different it is from using class B without extending class A if I dont want to use any of the objects of A?

I just started using JAVA to modify a service.

Comment: You can use `super` keyword to use pattern class method or instance variable. like `super.name`

Comment: No, this is not good practice.  For one thing, the `name` value in the `c` variable was never set to anything, so it's always going to be the default.  You have access to the base class' getter and setter from within the derived class, why not just use those?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you inherit a class, you also inherit all the public and protected methods and variables from the inherited. So you can just do

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append(this.getName()).append(", ");
   builder.append(this.getGender()).append(", ");
   return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

simply by calling `getName()` in your toString method or `super.getName()`

like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append(getName()).append(", ");
   builder.append(gender).append(", ");
   return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: yup, this could be done by simply calling getter function of specific field because of getter method always set with public access modifier. so it is simplest approach even though calling getter with super keyword also a good approach.

Answer (score 6):

Never forget the old adage: *You don't inherit your parent's privates.*

If you want `B` to have access to `A.name`, you have a couple of options:

- Change `name` to be either `public` (bad) or `protected` (better) in `A`.
- Access `name` through `A`'s setters and getters, e.g. `this.getName()`
- Use [reflection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html)

What you've currently done just returns the *default* value of `A.name` and not the value of name that actually belongs to your instance of `B`.

Comment: I cannot change the parent class, it is being used in several different projects. And I forgot to mention that class A belongs to a different package.

Comment: @spod The package that it's in is irrelevant for `public` or `protected` level. Anyway, your best bet is to just use the setters/getters provided or use reflection if you need it.